# Showing internal fields in Cognito Forms in confirmation email

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to create a  quiz consisting of 10 questions in Cognito Forms whereby a user will get a confirmation email if he scores more than 8. The confirmation form will show his answers and the correct answers alongside with it.

I have managed to do everything except for he part where the confirmation email can show the answers.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/WBPPropertyGroup1/TrainingQuiz

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Thank you for sharing your form as a template, I was able to make some updates to your template to help get this worked out.

The first thing I did was to remove your Content fields with the F/T answers and replaced them with Calculation fields with the title as 1 - 10 for each question. I then added the F/T answer to each one and marked the field to be shown 'Internally'.

I then added each question to the email confirmation and the corresponding Calculation field after the question so that the correct answer is shown after it. This will send the information inside of the message of your Confirmation Email. You will not have to include the entry details. You can see this in the following screenshot.

I have also added a link to the template that I used to set this up.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoFormsTestAccount/TrainingQuiz2

[image]

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you so  much for your help! The internal fields are showing up now in the confirmation page and it works great.

I do have one more question, is it possible to have them display alongside their answers? I have ticked "include entry details" in confirmation mail and it has the perfect template. Once again, thank you for your time!